# Finding id of a button

Tags: android, button

I have a button in my android app. Its reference is `button1`i.e.

`button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tv6);`

In some function, I receive a string with value `button1`. Using this string I need to get the `id` of the above button. How to do that.

Comment: yes its clear now, please check with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

use following:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(idName, "id", getPackageName());
```

By this method you would get id, and by id you can get View.

Comment: i am gettin `resID` equal to `0`

Comment: i do not have `idName`, i have reference as string only

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
Button mButton  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: i have `mButton` as string. How i use this to get id ?

Comment: you mean you get R.id.tv6 as a string so you want to get int id using this string. is that you mean???

Answer (score 0):

Having button in xml file as:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"/>
```

You can get id of it as:

```
Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just this:

```
int buttonId = R.id.button1;
```

Comment: `button1` i receive in string format not as a button reference. even then u cannot use above.